# Default order when selecting from a dataset where that data has been ordered during population

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

I have a lookup table linking employees to positions held whilst in the company. This data is held in a data set table with just employee ID and position ID columns.

[image: Position lookup screen shot]

I need to get the most recently help position for each employee.

Normally, I'd specify a sort order using:

```
DataTable.Select(<select statement>, <sort order>);
```

but using the existing table doesn't give me that option as the sort fields haven't been stored.

If the data table is populated with each employees positions listed in descending date order, can I rely on that data being selected in the same order?

I'm concious that I could just add the date fields to the table but this is an old piece of code and I want to make as few changes as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this link](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t99197-sort-order-problem-with-datatable-select-method.html) which shows me I either need to assign a primary key or use a sort order on the extract.